# Tracking help center article link clicks in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, seo

My company's support department uses freshdesk to handle our help desk tickets and also to host our solution center articles. I am trying to track when users click links to our help center articles that we put in our ticket replies. So far I've been trying to do this by using utm parameters, and creating a unique campaign for each article. I am running into difficulty programmatically accessing the text area where we type our replies to add the utm parameters to links before they are sent out. I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this that I'm not thinking of. I know this is pretty specific, but any ideas are very Appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related as it is soe it may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off topic, as the tag specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Managing distinct campaign names for each help article may be a hassle. I'd suggest you turn to event tracking for this kind of task. You may have set up sending an event to analytics each time a link to help article is clicked and put the URL of the link to some of the event parameter e.g. 'event action' or 'event label'. So then you can get the event data in Behavior > Top events reports for each link
Some links for you to explore:

- [About Google Analytics Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en)
- [Tracking link clicks with Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en)
- [Event tracking with google analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)